# Oracle 10g xe database error when connecting ORA-12528

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I am trying to connect to my local database **Oracle 10g XE** however i am getting the following error **ORA - 12528**. This connection was working and this issue suddenly arose. I did **LSNRCTL status** the results are under:

What can i do to resolve this problem?

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

```
LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                03-JAN-2014 15:37:04
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 3 min. 27 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         C:\Development\oracle_xe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\ser
ver\network\log\listener.log
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ITDEV-DARIN)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "XE_XPT" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Seems like you might have more luck with a connection issue on http://dba.stackexchange.com/.  An oracle dba would have better diagnosis skills here than a typical developer, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [error messages manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/net12500.htm#sthref3569):

> **ORA-12528: TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new connections**
>       **Cause**: All instances supporting the service
>   requested by the client reported that they were blocking the new
>   connections. This condition may be temporary, such as at instance
>   startup.
>       **Action**: Attempt the connection again. If error persists, then
>   contact the administrator to check the status of the instances.

This isn't really a listener issues - the database appears to unavailable. You'll need to look at the alert log to see why. You could also try to connect locally using SQL*Plus; if you try to connect as a normal user it might give some indication (e.g. an archiver error, maybe), and if you connect as SYS and try to start up you'll probably get an even better idea. Looking for errors in the alert log might be more direct though.

Comment: I connected as sysdba to sys and i executed a startup force and i saw the database was not mounted. How can i mount the database somehow it has been unmounted

Comment: It will have said why it wouldn't mount, and the alert log probably has more detail. I'd suggest you open a new question on [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com) with the full text of the SQL*Plus session, so it includes everything you typed and exactly what messages and errors you got back.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the DB instance as sysdba: run this command:

*sqlplus / as sysdba*

SQL> *shutdown*

SQL> *startup*

In my case the server run out of space so I need to delete some unnecessary files first.